# Problems with FORECASTING in R

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a problem with forecasting in R. 
First of all, this is an example of the original dataset (CW_data_noNA):

```
Loading date  Year Built  Vessel Type  Cargo Size  Week
2019-08-22    2011         Medium       30000       34
2019-09-01    2004         Aframax      80000       35
2019-08-30    2005         Panamax      60000       35
2019-09-01    2000         VLCC         270000      35
2019-08-29    2001         VLCC         270000      35
2019-09-03    2003         Suezmax      130000      36
2019-08-26    2002         Medium       30000       34
```

I have to create a weekly time series (showing the total number of fixed ships and the cargo capacity), and then to use naïve and simple moving average to provide one-week ahead forecast.

```
Weekly_base <- CW_data_noNA %>% group_by(Week) %>% summarize(Number_of_fix = n(),cargo_capacity = sum(`Cargo Size`))

Weekly_ts <- ts(Weekly_base, start = c(2019, 32), frequency = 52)

demand_training <- window(Weekly_ts, start = c(2019,32), end=c(2019,41))   
demand_test <- window(Weekly_ts, start = c(2019,42))

naive(demand_training, h=1)
```

The problem occured with the code above is that  it gives me the forcasting not for the variables (number of fix and cargo capacity) but for the week itself. This is how the result looks like:

```
           Point Forecast     Lo 80      ....
2019.788    42              -23879066   ....
```

Can someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: please upload sample data: dput(head(table))

Comment: I did it, it is in the above part of my question.

Answer (score 0):

In the line where you generate your `Weekly_ts`, you're currently supplying the whole data frame, i.e.

```
Weekly_ts <- ts(Weekly_base, start = c(2019, 32), frequency = 52)
```

I guess the help of `naive` (`?naive`) is a bit ambiguous(?), as it states that `y` should be

> a numeric vector or time series of class `ts`

and you definitely supplied an object of class `ts`. However, in this case you supplied multiple series when it is expecting just the one. Simply select the one you want and it should forecast the correct series

```
relevant_variable <- Weekly_base %>% 
  select(cargo_capacity)#change cargo_capacity to Number_of_fix to change variable

Weekly_ts <- ts(relevant_variable, start = c(2019, 32), frequency = 52)
```

Or more direct

```
Weekly_ts <- ts(Weekly_base$cargo_capacity, start = c(2019, 32), frequency = 52)
```